# How to create properly a trigger to update a column in the same table

Tags: postgresql, triggers, postgis

I am not sure about what is the best method to execute this.
I have a form that takes coordinates from position(lon,lat) and other information. Using lon and lat i have to make a point using postgis in my `geom` column( i created it: `select AddGeometryColumn('public','datos','geom',4326,'point',2)`).

In my first attemp i tried to send it from client using ajax

```
lon:$("#lon").text(),
lat:$("#lat").text(),
geom:"ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint("+$("#lon").text()+","+$("#lat").text()+"),4326)"
       or "point("+$("#lon").text()+" "+$("#lat").text()+")"
```

then in php i got the info

```
$lon =$_POST['lon'];
$lat =$_POST['lat'];
$geom =$_POST['geom'];
$set_interview = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO datos(lon,lat,geom) VALUES (:lon,:lat,:geom)");
```

In localhost it worked perfectly but when i deployed it i got error about server
[image: ERROR]

So i thought about triggers and created this one first for localhost but it doesn't work:

```
create function SP_crearGeometry() returns trigger
as
$$
begin 
update datos set geom='point(-77.09097 -11.944051)';
return new;
End
$$
language plpgsql

create trigger TR_update before update on datos
for each row
execute procedure SP_crearGeometry()


update datos set lon=datos.lon, lat=datos.lat where id=34
```

```
HINT:  "point(da" <-- parse error at position 8 within geometry
QUERY:  update datos set geom='point(datos.lon datos.lat)'
CONTEXT:  función PL/pgSQL sp_creargeometry() en la línea 3 en sentencia SQL
SQL state: XX000
```

Also tried changing `update datos set geom=ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(lon,lat),4326);`
but doesnt work
I would like to know what is the better way to implement this function(fron client side or server) and how to improve it to make it work because none of them work deployed

Comment: The error is from a different version of the function then the one you show in your function. Update your question with the correct version of the function.  Though I'm going to say this: `point(datos.lon datos.lat)` is not going to work as you need to use [Dynamic SQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) to do this.

Comment: To make sure I got your use case correctly: you wish to store the *hard coded* coordinate pair `point(-77.09097 -11.944051)` in the column `geom` every time `lon` and `lat`gets updated?

Comment: My idea Is to save info in geom column using lon lat, when users fill a form, `point(lo lat)` works on localhost but i proyecto has another version of Postgres so the sentence to sabe geom Is `ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(lon,lat),4326)` but ir doesn't work. I was looking for an advice how to store geom using thise values ( from cliente side using: geom `ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(lon,lat),4326)` then receive ir with PHP then store ir un the table) or from cliente side Sent only those 2 values, then un PHP usé thise values for example:`inser into tablet(geom) values( 'ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(' .:lon..

Comment: But I don't know how to replace un bindParam, for example before executing i set `...('lon',$_lon,PDO::PARAM_STR)` but un this case how could i replace this because I am jsing 2 vales ti get anothet one.

Comment: Also thought about make a trigger to send lon, lat AND database make all the proccess but ir didn't work